# Inbox search shows only emails received before certain date

Tags: vba, email, outlook

The follow MS Office 2010 VBA excerpt loops through emails in Outlook inbox only shows emails that have been received before a certain date( more than a week ago).

```
For Each obj In olFolder.Items
If TypeName(obj) = "MailItem" Then
    Debug.Print obj.Subject & Chr(10) & obj.SenderEmailAddress & Chr(10) & obj.ReceivedTime
End If
Next
```

Many more emails show in the very same account and very same folder in Outlook itself.

What can this issue be?

Comment: If you have `On Error Resume Next` somewhere, remove it.

Comment: I test for mailitem

Comment: How about actually *casting* it to `MailItem`. Are you late-binding or early-binding? You're *in Outlook*? Then you can do `If TypeOf obj Is MailItem` instead of that stringly-typed name check. FWIW you weren't "testing for mailitem" 3 minutes ago, so give us a break here. Why not include an actual [mcve] that reproduces the actual problem, instead of arbitrarily removing important bits of context code until all we can do is throw random ideas in the air?

Comment: You also haven't answered the question - **are you sure the script does not raise an error?**

Comment: Script does not raise errors. I did not copy the complete example because I am a beginner and tried and commented tons of things out.

Comment: I researched the issue and I am inclined to think that it is related to indexing of the messages.

Comment: Are you using Restrict Method ? can you show more code

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the script does not raise an error?  This will happen if you have an item other than MailItem (e.g. ReportItem or MeetingRequest) and you try to access a property not exposed by that object.

Comment: Yes. This is only for mailitem. It fails to detect more recent mail items.

Comment: Script does not raise errors. I did not copy the complete example because I am a beginner and tried and commented tons of things out.

Comment: @M U - this **is** the answer: one should not assume there are only MailItem objects in the Inbox.